# Assigning values in an array using calculations involving each element's index

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

My array has total 10 indices and I'm trying to set `array[0] = 1/1`, `array[1] = 1/2`, `array[2] = 1/3`, `array[4] = 1/4` and so on.

After the calculation I want to display the elements with `Sytem.out.println();`

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int VALUE =1;
    int[] array = new int[10];
    int counter=10;
    double result =0;
    for(int i =0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        array[0]=VALUE/i;
        array[1]=VALUE/i;
        array[2]=VALUE/i;
        array[3]=VALUE/i;
        array[4]=VALUE/i;
        array[5]=VALUE/i;
        array[6]=VALUE/i;
        array[7]=VALUE/i;
        array[8]=VALUE/i;
        array[9]=VALUE/i;

    System.out.println( array[0] +" " + array[1] +" " + array[2] +" " + array[3]+" " +  array[4]+" "+array[5]+" " +array[6] +" " + array[7]+" " +   array[8]+" " +  array[9]+" " +  array[10]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you simply just want `array[i] = VALUE/i;`

Comment: What do you think `array[0]=VALUE/i;` does?  What about `array[1]=VALUE/i;`, etc?  What will they do differently each time through the loop?

Comment: i thought that, the i changes every single turn (i  increasing by for loop +1) but it does not do that as i expect @azurefrog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems. The first is that your loop already takes care of going over each index in the array, so you can just do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = 1.0/(i+1);
    System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
}
```

The other is that you use an array of integers. By definition, an integer cannot be a fraction. Try using an array of doubles instead:

```
double[] array = new double[10];
```

Comment: Wasn't even thinking about how the OP defined the array. Good catch.

Comment: @Brandon would be a good idea to update your answer with the same =)

Comment: i've two questions. First of all thank you for your answer. I dont understand 2 thinks why didn't you use VALUE variabel. Second is does not i increase +1 already. If it is not why?

Comment: @LenaMonikaMarshall I simply used `1.0` instead of the `VALUE` variable - that's basically the same thing since `VALUE` was set to 1 anyway. You could use `VALUE` if you wanted (just set it to a double instead of an int). As for your other question, I divide by `(i + 1)` because on the first iteration of your loop, i is 0. In that case, you don't want to get 1 divided by 0, you want to get 1 divided by one. So you need to use `i + 1` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a loop and also doing it inside manually. Just use the loops iterations to calculate it, and use the value of `i` for your array values.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = VALUE/(i+1);
}

System.out.println( array[0] +" " + array[1] +" " + array[2] +" " + array[3]+" " +  array[4]+" "+array[5]+" " +array[6] +" " + array[7]+" " +   array[8]+" " +  array[9]);
```

---

Another problem, as mentioned by others, it that your result would be in fraction or floating point, and you are trying to store it in an `int` array

Use a float array instead

```
float[] array = new float[10];
```

Comment: Put parentheses around i+1 so it's VALUE/(i+1) and it'll be good to go.

Comment: @BrandonWillis, Thanks. Done.

Comment: Keep in mind storing the results of division using an integer.

Comment: @CubeJockey, I wasn't updating as that was mentioned in other answer. Never mind, Updated. :)

Comment: tthank you for reply @Pallavi. I write the code as you send and that's give eror.     Exception in thread "main"     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at kapital11.kaptal11.main(kaptal11.java:14)

Comment: @LenaMonikaMarshall, Yes, because of your print statement, I edited it. Check now. :)

Comment: thanks your patience @Pallavi :). If i wrote this time correctly, it just gives 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 the output :(